# Why would a person being brought up with a belief that is against the Creator's Will when we as muslim don't have to deal with such a situation?

Tags: quran, hadith, practical-islam, life

It is an extreme fact that very few people of other faiths are seen to convert to Islam.
This means that converting to Islam is a little harder than usual for those of us who were born into a muslim family.I do not believe that Allah 'azzawajal has done injustice to them because I know from Allah's attributes that Allah is not unjust. The answer I really want to know is why would a person go astray on such an important issue early in life and why would he live with a belief that is against the way of our only true Creator(Allah 'azzawajal) when we do not have to deal with such a situation? This ia the question that i've in my mind as well as some friends of mine have asked me this and I've no answer.....so I want you to elaborate this with deeper logic and evidences from the Qur'an and authentic aahadith!

Comment: "And We have certainly diversified for the people in this Qur'an from every [kind] of example, but most of the people refused [anything] except disbelief." (17:89)

Answer (score 1):

What is the will of the Creator? Your question is confusing and vague. Your mind is woven into several different topics, each of which has separate answers. The will of the Creator in creating diverse thoughts and beliefs and our being born a Muslim and oppressing non-Muslims and ....
God created man to be God-knowing and God-fearing, endowed with the power of reason and thought, and possessed of will and authority, and sent divine prophets to guide mankind. So God does not create anyone an infidel, a Christian, a Jew, etc .; Rather, it is man who deviates due to his own misuse or environmental conditions.
The Holy Prophet (PBUH) says: "A child is born by the nature of monotheism, his parents call him a Jew or a Christian."
There have been various human beings who, although born and raised in non-Muslim and even anti-Islamic families, turned to Islam when they found the light of truth in adulthood.
Humans have the power of reason and thought and can discover anything of their own free will.
I will give an example. The Quran is available everywhere, even on the Internet. Any literate person can find and study it. If he does not understand somewhere, he can ask a Qur'anic expert. Who's fault that no one wants to read the Quran ?! That in many cases they misunderstand the verses and do not want to ask the expert, who is to blame ??! Who really lost? The fact that no one wants to become literate has harmed him first and foremost. And then society will suffer.
That is why we humans must first develop ourselves and our thoughts and beliefs. And help our friends, family and community grow further. Just like what we do to make society literate.

https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa690

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is tested differently. Allah (swt) tests everyone. Allah (swt) may bless a people with being born into a Muslim family but then they may be tested with calamities, or tested by poverty, or drought, or famine, or war, or no home, or poor health. Another people he may bless them with good health, wealth, friends and family, luxuries, freedom, safety, security, and an easy life but may test them by raising them up with a non-Muslim family and a kufr society. And their test is different. Allah (swt) tests them so that if he wills when someone gives them dawah, will they accept or not. Will they choose iman or will they choose kufr? Will they choose the path of truth, good and righteousness or will they choose the path of falsehood, desires and evil if the message of truth comes to them while they’re not a Muslim? All of this is also a test